# Effective search of Variables view in xCode?

Tags: xcode, debugging

How do I effectively search self and all variables under it in the Variables view, when on a breakpoint? It seams like the search-box in the lower right only search what is expanded and I can't find any "expand all" option. What is your trick?

Answer (score 0):

If you option-click on the disclosure triangle, it should expand all the children of the object. (Note that sometimes it only shows one level, but if you option-click to shut it and option-click to open it again, *then* it shows all the children.)

Also, note that you can sort the variables in alphabetical order by right-clicking (or control-clicking) on a variable and choosing "Sort By" and then "Name". That can also make it easier to find stuff.